# How to get a table row except the last table-data

Tags: jquery, html

why do i get the whole row ?

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Print</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Dummy1.1</td>
            <td>Dummy1.2</td>
            <td>Dummy1.3</td>
            <td>Dummy1.4</td>
            <td><button>Print</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dummy2.1</td>
            <td>Dummy2.2</td>
            <td>Dummy2.3</td>
            <td>Dummy2.4</td>
            <td><button>Print</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('table tbody tr td:last-child').on('click', function(){
            var $row = $(this).parent('tr:not(:last-child)').text();
            console.log($row);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to print the row except the print table-data when i klick the button.
My code don't work properly because it show's me the whole row.

thanks for help

Comment: i found a solution var $row = $(this).parent().find('td:not(:last-child)').text();

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if the `tr` is not the last child and trying to find a parent with that selector.It should be

```js
$('table tbody tr td:last-child').on('click', function() {
  var $row = $(this).parent().find('td:not(:last-child)').text();
  console.log($row);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Print</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Dummy1.1</td>
      <td>Dummy1.2</td>
      <td>Dummy1.3</td>
      <td>Dummy1.4</td>
      <td>
        <button>Print</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dummy2.1</td>
      <td>Dummy2.2</td>
      <td>Dummy2.3</td>
      <td>Dummy2.4</td>
      <td>
        <button>Print</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```